# Centos7: не запускается vsftpd

Tags: centos7, vsftpd

Я в этих системных настройках новый, я только учусь.
Купил vds поставил туда httpd, и запустил сайт, но понадобился ftp, я установил vsftpd, и настроил.
Вот конфиг:

```
listen=YES
background=YES
pam_service_name=FTPD
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_root=/
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
userlist_deny=NO
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users/
force_dot_files=YES
local_umask=022

pasv_min_port=49000
pasv_max_posrt=55000
```

Но при запуске (systemctl start vsftpd) выводит ошибку что неверен конфиг. 
Помогите пожалуйста, как я могу решить свою проблему?

Comment: Смотрите логи, там должна быть ошибка.

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, а где логи? 

Comment: /var/log/vsftpd.log

Comment: А, я проверял его, он пустой

Comment: В конфиге что редактировали? Насколько я помню, он по-умолчанию уже рабочий должен быть.

Comment: Простите, вопрос не понял

Comment: Как указано в конфиге, я создал папку users в ней настройки для отдельных пользователей, также я создал user_list в нём список пользователей.

Comment: Придётся тогда без ftp.

Comment: Используйте SFTP, для него ничего дополнительно не нужно, он работает через SSH

Comment: Я знаю, я его сейчас и использую, но другим как давать? Если sftp давать то это не безопасно. Спасибо что попробовали помочь.

Comment: Я бы попробовал найти другую инструкцию по настройке vsftpd, удалил на сервере все настройки и пакет vsftpd и попробовал бы снова. Инструкций сейчас много всяких)

Comment: Я пробовал, пробовал и с хранением  пользователей бд. Запущу centos 7 дома на компе и попробую установить vsftpd, может дело в vds хостинга

Comment: Тоже правильно. А вообще, я бы посоветовал установить какую-нибудь панельку. Например, VestaCP. Она сразу и FTP настроит и веб-сервер. Не помню, работает ли она под CentOS, у меня Debian на VDS.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую установить панель.